# Splitting 3D Spheres with 3D Walls (lines converted to 3D) in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, 3d, 3d-analyst, multipatch

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

I would like to split spheres (created from 3D buffers) in half using 3D fences/walls (lines converted to 3D).  Both datasets are multipatches.

The purpose of doing this step is to create hemispherical features that represent downwind directions from air quality monitoring sites. The basic idea is to measure a variety of land use and other variables that may explain variation in observed air quality.

I figured out one workaround by creating 3D boxes (see 2nd fig) from one-sided buffers of lines that bisect the circular buffers (2D version of spheres), creating 3d boxes from these buffers, then using 3d intersect but if there is a more elegant solution - i.e., a way to **split** multipatch features, that would be helpful.

[image]

[image]